# HiRedis:: How to insert a blank string in Redis list using LPUSH

Tags: redis, hiredis

I am using redisCommand of the hiredis library to do something like this:

```
LPUSH list1 a b "" c d "" e
```

where "" means I want to insert empty element to the list. It works fine when I do it from command line on redis but when I pass this as a command on hiredis, it doesn't work and the element ends up being "" instead of empty.
Any work around?

Here's how I called redisCommand:

```
reply = (redisReply *) redisCommand(c,"LPUSH list1 a b c "" c d "" e);
```

I have tried putting single quotes, backslashes etc also

Comment: How did you call redisComand? Any example?

Comment: Added the example

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of binary safe strings in Redis.
Keep adding binary strings to your list using LPUSH command, as shown below:

redisReply *reply = redisCommand(context, "LPUSH list1 %b %b %b", "a", strlen("a"), "", 0, "b", strlen("b"));

The output will be:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> lrange list1 0 -1
1) "b"
2) ""
3) "a"
```

HTH,
Swanand

Comment: The problem is that the list is huge and I want to connect to redis only once

Answer (score 0):

> If the number of elements you want to push to list is fixed: use `redisCommand` with the formatted parameters

```
const char *list = "list-name";
const char *non_empty_val = "value";
const char *empty_val = "";
/* or use %b to push binary element, as the other answer mentioned. */
redisReply *reply = (redisReply*)redisCommand(redis,
                          "lpush %s %s %s", list, non_empty_val, empty_val);
```

> If the number of elements is dynamic: use `redisCommandArgv`

```
int argc = 4;  /* number of arguments including command name. */

const char **argv = (const char**)malloc(sizeof(const char**) * argc);
argv[0] = strdup("lpush");
argv[1] = strdup(list);
argv[2] = strdup(non_empty_val);
argv[3] = strdup(empty_val);

/* specify the length of each argument. */
size_t *argv_len = (size_t*)malloc(sizeof(size_t) * argc);
for (int i = 0; i < argc; ++i)
    argv_len[i] = strlen(argv[i]);

redisReply *reply = (redisReply*)redisCommandArgv(redis, argc, argv, argv_len);
```